dataframe plot histogram boundary bins
bins  = [x for x in range(-10, 11)]
df['val'].plot(kind='hist', bins=bins)

I want to put all the out-range values >10 or <-10 into the boundary right/left bin but not change their widths. btw suppose the max/min value of df is dynamic.
I can build two boundary bins like [-9999, 0] and [0, 9999], but their width will be extremely large. Another way is to clip the data of df['val'] by
np.clip(df['val'], a_max= bins[-1], a_min=bins[0])

Is there an easy way to achieve my goal without change df

If you want to have equal-width bars representing differently wide intervals you'll need to put interval labels to the bars, otherwise it would be unclear.
Here's an example with cut-off values:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': 10 * np.random.randn(1000)})

bins = list(range(-10,11))
df.plot.hist(bins=bins)


Now, to add the out-of-range bars, we use cut to calculate the intervalls and value_counts to count the values:
pd.cut(df.val, [-9999] + bins + [9999]).value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(width=1)



happened another issue: it is not equal weighted, I have another para weights: N, bins, patches = ax.hist(df['val], weights=weights, bins=bins)
